# Bootstrap 4 Cheese Burger button not responding outside code pen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This may be a relatively easy to solve problem but well not for me, hence any help will be appreciated. Working on a portfolio project from  https://freecodecamp.org I realized that when I copy my code to VS code and view in my browser, the navbar's cheese burger button doesn't respond.

But when I take this same action in codepen's editor, it works like a charm.
here is a link to the page in codepen https://codepen.io/stealthman22/full/PeZvNK/.Also the code snippet for the cheese burger button:

```
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarnavbarSupportedContent"
      aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
```

Please what could be wrong?
Cheeers!.

Answer (score 0):

Okay So I tested your code on my machine and I found two issues on it

First the the boostrap was declared before jquery.min.js. When using boostrap it is a good practice to load the jquery before it as the former has some dependencies from the jquery library itself

Second the integrity SHA384 of your Bootstrap CDN was invalid.

It throws error on this when you open the console

```
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'
```

I Replace your CDN with these and it work like a charm

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here is it looking fine on the browser now
[image]

Comment: Thanks boss @keysl You are amazing. The first problem I thought the other way round. I felt everything had to come after  bootstrap.

And for the second I honestly don't even know the meaning and use of all that stuff. Please would you mind taking out more time to explain to me. Thank you for your time really. Would implement your fixes right away
Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, I had to stick with my original jQuery code, because that particular library was necessary for my scrolling navbar.

Hence I followed your arrangement, and copied your Bootstrap 4 cdn link. And it's all working like a charm. Thank you so much